# Can we have two foreign keys pointing to the same table in one TypeORM entity?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have two entity models (*Match* and *Partner*), one of which contains two references to the other (*partner1* and *partner2*).

```
@Entity("partner")
export class PartnerEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string

    @Column()
    text: string
}

@Entity("match")
export class MatchEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string

    @ManyToOne(() => PartnerEntity, partner => partner.id)
    @JoinColumn()
    partner1?: PartnerEntity

    @ManyToOne(() => PartnerEntity, partner => partner.id)
    @JoinColumn()
    partner2?: PartnerEntity
}
```

I am trying to persist a MatchEntity object using the Repository class from TypeORM like this:

```
this.matchRepository.save({
    partner1: { text: "AAA" },
    partner2: { text: "BBB" }
})
```

However, the same value is being saved for *partner1* and *partner2*. I can confirm both that the object is correct and that the row stored in the database has the same value for the two foreign keys. The following object is returned:

```
{
    id: "c58f3ea7-5002-463d-92e7-94d0c2992784",
    partner1: { id: "10978976-d120-4e48-a490-eba62e7c06e5", text: "AAA" },
    partner2: { id: "10978976-d120-4e48-a490-eba62e7c06e5", text: "AAA" }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Is there a way to make this work?

Options that were considered but that I'd rather avoid for this use case:

- Implementing a ManyToMany relationship instead (convert the two fields into an array with two positions)
- Inserting new rows with explicit SQL queries using `Repository.createQueryBuilder()`